# Switch users with sudo or su in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, su

I inherited this. Long story short I have an XML file that is calling a shell to run some commands. Everything I have tried has failed at the second su in the script. Here are some of the failure messages:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Or

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Or

```
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V blah blah blah
```

Here is snippet of my script. It only fails at the second `su` attempt:

```
  <script language="shell"><![CDATA[
                  echo Doing some stuff
                  sudo -u adminuser /path/to/a/script/script
                  echo Emailing this stuff...
              su emailuser -c "mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'Your stuff is ready' -- ${WHOEVER_PARAM_RECIPIENT} < /tmp/emailingstuff.html"
                ]]></script>
```

I've played around with permissions so much that I forgot where I was with them. Here they are currently in sudoers:

```
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file

Defaults:emailuser !authenticate

adminuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su - emailuser
adminuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su emailuser
adminuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo su emailuser

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: You know that XML is a markup language and not some sort of "scripting" language right? Why you must parse xml as script?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something in the `su` configuration that allows the user running these commands to run commands as `emailuser` with `su`, the command `su emailuser -c …` will prompt for `emailuser`'s password. The use of `sudo` is always explicit.

Given your sudo rules, you probably wanted

```
sudo su emailuser -c …
```

But your sudo rules are strange: there's no point in authorizing `sudo` only to run `su` to yet another user. Change them to specify the target user, and forget about `su`.

```
scriptuser ALL = (adminuser) NOPASSWD: /path/to/a/script/script ""
scriptuser ALL = (emailuser) NOPASSWD: mutt
```

Note that since Mutt allows shell escapes, restricting the command as `emailuser` to mutt doesn't really increase security, but it may reduce accidental misuse. In your script, use

```
sudo -H -u emailuser mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'Your stuff is ready' -- ${WHOEVER_PARAM_RECIPIENT} < /tmp/emailingstuff.html
```

Since you're calling sudo from a script, make sure that the `requiretty` flag is turned off in the `sudoers` file (it's off by default, but some distribution add it, despite the extremely limited circumstances where it could concievably improve security).

Comment: Thanks for the insight and helpful repsonse. I think I'm getting closer to the solution. I recreated the emailuser account. Removed all the sillyness from sudoers and now I get "su: must be run from a terminal." The other portion of the script executes fine. It's just the second su that is failing. Still stumped.

Comment: @mistermister As I wrote in my answer, change your script to call `sudo` only, not `su`.

Comment: Ah. That seems to be working. The last part of the issue is that mutt wont send the email because "/home/adminuser/sent is not a mailbox"

Comment: I tried the command you provided as the adminuser and could not send the email. When I try it as the emailuser it works. This works outside of the script without sudo -u. Still stumped.

Comment: @mistermister `sudo` doesn't set some environment variables, maybe mutt relies on one? In particular, sudo may or may not set `HOME` — add the `-H` option to force it so set `HOME` to the home directory of the target user.

Comment: Don't forget !requiretty

Comment: @tylerl Good point, I hadn't thought of that. Though it is off in the sudoers file shown in the question.